# Passing "flag" Arguments to Systemd Services

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, systemd, services

I have a Systemd service that calls a script. That script takes it's own arguments, some of which are named arguments. I currently have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=no
User=corvus
Environment="ARGS=%I"
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh $ARGS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I am attempting to call the script with something like:

```
$ sudo systemctl start myservice@"--flag argument".service
```

However this doesn't seem to work and the `--` part of the flag seems to get converted into `//`. The service looks like it is running, but doesn't seem to be and in the `systemd status` information I can see where it has substituted the `--` with `//`.

I have attempted to escape the `-` by prefixing them with a `\` however that also doesn't work and the service doesn't actually start with this approach.

Any pointers or things to try would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion of `-` to `/` is for allowing paths in the template argument and other parts of the unit name. This is covered in `man systemd.unit`, [section "String Escaping for Inclusion in Unit Names"](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#String%20Escaping%20for%20Inclusion%20in%20Unit%20Names):

> Sometimes it is useful to convert arbitrary strings into unit names.
> To facilitate this, a method of string escaping is used, in order to
> map strings containing arbitrary byte values (except `NUL`) into valid
> unit names and their restricted character set. A common special case
> are unit names that reflect paths to objects in the file system
> hierarchy. Example: a device unit `dev-sda.device` refers to a device
> with the device node `/dev/sda` in the file system.
>
> The escaping algorithm operates as follows: given a string, any "`/`"
> character is replaced by "`-`", and all other characters which are not
> ASCII alphanumerics, "`:`", "`_`" or "`.`" are replaced by C-style
> "`\x2d`" escapes. In addition, "`.`" is replaced with such a C-style
> escape when it would appear as the first character in the escaped
> string.
>
> [...]
>
> This escaping is fully reversible, as long as it is known whether the
> escaped string was a path (the unescaping results are different for
> paths and non-path strings). The
> [systemd-escape(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-escape.html)
> command may be used to apply and reverse escaping on arbitrary
> strings. Use **`systemd-escape --path`** to escape path strings, and
> **`systemd-escape`** without `--path` otherwise.

So:

```
% systemd-escape  -- "--flag argument"
\x2d\x2dflag\x20argument
```

You should use `\x2d\x2dflag\x20argument` as the template argument.

Comment: This has helped overcome the first hurdle, however I have now noticed that the string "--flag argument" gets passed to the script as a single argument. My script uses a `while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do` loop to loop over the arguments looking for flag-value pairs ($1 and $2 in the script respectively).As there is only a single argument provided from systemd, this functionality is broken. Is there a way of fixing this at the service level or do I need to modify my script to account for it?

Comment: You could try something like `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'set -f; /path/to/script.sh %I'` to have a shell do whitespace splitting for you (you might need to use `/bin/sh -c 'set -f; /path/to/script.sh $@' sh %I` - I don't remember how exactly quoting and templating mix in systemd units. However, if this is your script and you can modify it, I strongly recommend using environment variables (`FLAG_VAR=argument` and then use the template argument to set an `EnvironmentFile`) or maybe reading flags from a file instead of forcing command-line arguments directly into the template argument.